# NextJS- How handle redirect, meanwhile my strategy returns an error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to fetch the URL entered in the browser to make some redirect in my NextJS custom server. This error occurs only in dev mode, no in production mode, so is it normal ? there is some modification to do on the devmode to handle that ?

I have tried to use the pathname object. Sadly when I first entered  an URL in my address bar, my pathname firstly returns:

> /_next/static/chunks/0.js

I have tried with req.rawHeaders. But my console returns nothing till the 15th trial:

> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :
>
> req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js :  /pathTargeted // work ! but a little bit in late ..

I have also tried with req.headers.referer but even, the first path returns is not the path I have entered in the URL.

The result is that I fall in a 404 error. So how avoid this and always fetch the real address entered in the browser ? That exactly my problem.

Here my reactjs snippet:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"; 
import style from "./BlogHubTemplate.module.css";

import storeWrapper from "../../HOC/storeWrapper/storeWrapper"
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Router from 'next/router'


class BlogHubTemplate extends Component { 

    redirectPost = (postCategory, postTitle) => { 
        Router.replace(`/${postCategory}/${postTitle}`) 
    }
```

here my custom next.server js:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
 createServer((req, res) => {
 // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
 // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
 const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
 const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl; 

 console.log("req.headers in next.server.js : ", req.headers.referer.substr(22))
 console.log("req.rawHeaders path in next.server.js : ", req.rawHeaders[11].substr(22))
```

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: If you have a repo with the minimum reproducible setup that would be awesome.

Comment: here the repo: https://github.com/Hocoh/redirect_next . It should specifically reproduce the case and when you will try to go on the blog post's page, you'll firstly have a 404 error, come back to me if you have any question, you can launch the repo with "yarn dev" command, thanks

Comment: @HoCo_ you can add me as contributor to your repo, and I will window.location in all files, my github: odykyi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a next.js issue

just add `decodeURIComponent` in every place where you use `window.location.pathname`

---

28 code line  https://github.com/Hocoh/redirect_next/blob/master/ui/pages/post.js#L29

instead of:

```
  var postFullPath = window.location.pathname.substr(1) ;
```

shuld be:

```
  var postFullPath = decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname).substr(1) ;
```

---

---

38 code line  https://github.com/Hocoh/redirect_next/blob/master/ui/pages/blog.js#L38

instead of:

```
var pageTargeted = window.location.pathname.substr(11) ;
```

shuld be:

```
var pageTargeted = decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname).substr(11) ;
```

---

13 code line

https://github.com/Hocoh/redirect_next/blob/master/ui/components/BlogHubTemplate/utils/Pagination/Pagination.js#L13

instead of

```
   window.location.pathname = `blog/page/${pageTargeted}`
```

shoud be:

```
  Router.push(decodeURIComponent(`blog/page/${pageTargeted}`))
```

---

---

10 code line

https://github.com/Hocoh/redirect_next/blob/master/ui/components/BlogHubTemplate/utils/Pagination/PaginationMain/PaginationMain.js#L10

instead of:

```
window.location.pathname = `blog/page/${pageTargeted}`
```

should be:

```
  Router.push(decodeURIComponent(`blog/page/${pageTargeted}`))
```

---

code line 31

https://github.com/Hocoh/redirect_next/blob/master/ui/components/BlogHubTemplate/BlogHubTemplate.js#L31

instead of:

```
Router.replace(`/${postCategory}/${postTitle}`);
```

should be:

```
Router.push(decodeURIComponent(`/${postCategory}/${postTitle}`));
```

**and add `decodeURIComponent`  to another files**

Comment: @HoCo_ pls define here your routes https://github.com/Hocoh/redirect_next/blob/master/ui/routes.js , you can just write in comments your routes, and I will it rewrite it to nextjs routes